# Call class method from another class without inheritance and global in python

Tags: python

I'm absolutely new to python. I'm more familiar with C++, Java and was trying to do the following :

```
class A():
   def P(self, param):

class B():
   def Q(self):
     obj = A()
     obj.P("printThis")
```

But I get an error saying :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

I know with C++, Java you can initialize an object and call methods. I don't want to create global variables, nor use inheritance. I just want to know if there's a way to call another class method.

I tried to follow the steps from this:
[Using instances from other classes, overriding and separating values of x and y from a Point(x,y) from one class to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123096/using-instances-from-other-classes-overriding-and-separating-values-of-x-and-y), but it didn't work out.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

In the code I've written, class A and B are as follows :

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):   
        def form(self, display=""):
                form = """<!doctype html>
                                        <head>
                                        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                                        <title> Trial </title>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                        <div>
                                                <b>Enter some text</b>
                                        </div>
                                        <form action="/trial" method="post">
                                                <textarea name="text" placeholder="Enter text here...">%(text)s</textarea>
                                                        <div>
                                                        <input type="submit" value="Enter">
                                                </div>
                                        </form>
                                </body>
                        </html>"""
                self.response.write(form % {"text":display})

class ResponseText(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def post(self):
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
                text_entered = self.request.get('text')
                result = self.escape_html(text_entered)
                m = MainPage()
                m.form(result)
```

Comment: Are you defining `B` inside `A`? That is what your indentation looks like. If so, you are calling `A` from inside `B` before you have finished defining `A`.

Comment: No. Suppose A has a function P. I didn't write it out. And then there's a separate class B with function Q that should call A.P()

Comment: If class `B` is meant to be separate from `A` then you should not define `B` inside `A` which is what your indentation is currently doing. I guessed that you did not mean to do that, and answered the question on the basis of that guess.

Comment: Yes,  you understood correctly. Thanks.

Comment: If the answer worked for you then please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amended your indentation (to what I think you meant) and did this:

```
class A():
   def P(self, param):
       print(param)
class B():
   def Q(self):
     obj = A()
     obj.P("printThis")
```

And it seems to me to work:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.Q()
printThis
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'.

Comment: @user7999116 In that case, your problem is with the line `self.response.write(form % {"text":display})` in `MainPage.form`. Your `MainPage` instance's `response` attribute is None – I'm not familiar with webapp2, but could the problem be that you're creating your own `MainPage` and not telling it about the response that is presumably only stored at `ResponseText.response`?

Comment: I'm just beginning with webapp2, so it's entirely possible that could be the issue. However, I have no idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on Python version.
I write the code

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,a = True):
        if a:
            self.a = 10
        self.b = 20
    def b(self):
        print('---')
        self.dd = 30

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    def c(self):
        print(self.b)
        print(self.a)

    def d(self):
        A.b(self)


b = B()

b.c()
b.d()
print(b.dd)
```

and I can run it with python 3.5<, but i doesn't work with Python 2.x

I'm curious how to make it in python 2.x without using inheritance